# Vector container of variable types in a template class

Tags: c++, templates

I have template class with one variable data type `template <class outputT>`.
Inside the class I have private variable `vector< outputT > outputData`.
So the `outputT` is meant to be `complex<double>` or `vector< complex<double> >`. I have a constructor in which one of the arguments is `int N` giving the size of the `outputData` vector. In this constructor I initialize `outputData` like this:

```
ouputData.resize(N);
```

When I create an instance of the class with the option `complex<double>` everything is fine.
But if I create an instance with the option `vector< complex<double> >` and try to call an element of o`outputData` (from a public function `getOutpuData()`) it gives me `segmentation fault`. So obviously something is wrong with the memory storage of data, but what is it?
Also when `vector< complex<double> >` is used for the template the input vectors of this type are of size 2.
I guess my initialization `ouputData.resize(N);` is incorrect but not sure!
Ok so this is my class:

```
template <class inputT, class outputT>
class LubichInverse {
    public:
        LubichInverse(inputT (*fofs_In)(complex<double>), double R_In,
                      double dt_In, int N_In, int L_In, int M_In = 1):
                      fofs(fofs_In), R(R_In), dt(dt_In), N(N_In), L(L_In), M(M_In) {

            outputData.resize(N);
        }

        void calculateInverse() {
            // do some stuff here to calculate outputData, e.g.:
            for( int n=0; n<N; n++) {
                complex<double> s( n, 2.0*n );
                outputData[n] = fofs(s);  // this one could be a source of memory bug!
            }
        }

        vector< outputT > getOutputData() {
            return outputData;
        }

    private:
        inputT (*fofs)(complex<double>);
        vector< outputT > outputData;
        double R;
        double dt;
        int N;
        int L;
        int M;
};
```

This is the implementation:

```
// this is a function to test the complex<double> version
complex<double> testScalar(complex<double> s_In) {
    return (1.0/(s_In-3.75));
}

// this is a function to test the vector< complex<double> > version
vector< complex<double> > testVector(complex<double> s_In) {
    vector< complex<double> > tmp(2);
    tmp[0] = 1.0/s_In;
    tmp[1] = 1.0/(s_In-3.75);
    return tmp;  // Probably this one returns dangling pointer, namely tmp?
}

int main() {
// this one works fine!
LubichInverse< complex<double>, complex<double> > tmp_01(testScalar, 0.32, 0.001, 1000, 1000);
tmp_01.calculateInverse();
vector< complex<double> > vec_01(tmp_01.getOutputData());
cout << vec_01[2] << endl;

// this one is the problem
LubichInverse< vector< complex<double> >, vector< complex<double> > > tmp_02(testVector, 0.32, 0.001, 1000, 1000);
tmp_02.calculateInverse();
vector< vector< complex<double> > > vec_02(tmp_02.getOutputData());
cout << vec_02[0][1] << endl; // namely here is the segmentation fault problem, if remove this line it does not complain!

return 0;
}
```

I have found the bug in my original `calculateInverse()` function

```
void calculateInverse() {
    double tmp_00(pid2/L);
    for( int n=0; n < N; n++) {
        double tmp_01(-n*tmp_00);
        double tmp_02(pow(R,-n)/L);
        // initialize outputData for the case l=0, this one was the problem
     // outputData[n] = fofs( BDF2(R/dt) ); // this one is correct
     // for ( int l=1; l<L; l++ ) {         // this one is correct
        for( int l=0; l < L; l++) { // here in the case l=0 is the issue
            complex<double> tmp_10(0.0,tmp_00*l);
            complex<double> s( BDF2(R*exp(tmp_10)) / dt );
            complex<double> tmp_11(0,tmp_01*l);
            outputData[n] += (fofs(s)*exp(tmp_11));   // here the left argument
            // of overloaded operator+= is a vector< complex<double> >
            // as is initialized in the constructor (just a pointer to null, I think)
            // while the right argument is a vector< complex<double> >
            // with size 2. So it is like adding vectors with zero size and size 2.
        }
        outputData[n] *= (tmp_02/dt);
    }
}
```

Excuse me for not giving the original function but it is with overloaded operators that I had to explain too, besides I didn't thought it will be the problem. Thanks though, I got that making simpler test is very helpful in localizing the problem.

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words. And 20 lines of code is worth more than 20 paragraphs describing it. Post a [mcve].

Comment: [Doesn't reproduce](https://ideone.com/O5WgYg),

Comment: Not the issue, but: do not store `N` redundantly as member - you can get it back via `outputData.size()` (*unless*, of course, the size of vector and `N` can change independently such that these values might differ in the future...).

Comment: no problem here either. Compiled it with both clang and g++, everything works.

Comment: @Pekov Just for understanding: `outputData.resize(N)` in the vector instantiation resizes the member vector, calling the default constructor for each contained vector, i. e. each inner vector is initialized empty. If you really had an empty `calculateInverse` function as *before* your edit, then `vec_02[0]` returns a reference to an *empty* vector and you got the access violation on accessing this one out of range (`vec_02[0]` **[1]**).

Comment: @Aconcagua It was a similar problem. I did an edit trying to explain the bug.